# When installing memcached I receive 'configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH'

Tags: linux, unix, gcc, memcached

When trying to install memcached on linux download the server from http://memcached.org/ I then extracted the .gz file to a dir. But when I try to install the application using the command :

```
./configure
```

I receive this error :

```
    checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
    checking whether build environment is sane... yes
    checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
    checking for gawk... gawk
    checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
    checking for gcc... no
    checking for cc... no
    checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/home/myDir/memcached/memcached-1.4.17':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
```

So I downloaded the C compiler from ftp://ftp.mirrorservice.org/sites/sourceware.org/pub/gcc/releases/gcc-4.8.2/ and once extracted I set my path to gcc-4.8.2/gcc but I receive same error.

Am I installing / setting the C compiler path correctly ?

Comment: Did you compile GCC 4.8? You need some C++ compiler to build it. And I would just suggest adding the relevant development packages. On Debian or Ubuntu try `sudo aptitude install gcc g++ build-essentials` then `sudo aptitude build-dep memcached`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thanks for your commend. I just needed to install GCC using yum : "yum install gcc"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install GCC is easy as command: `yum install gcc`

Go unix! :)